# debian/exim4: eading local mail with the mail command as root

Tags: email, exim, root

I am using a network-less LXC container with a small debian stretch setup, which contains exim4 and probably, nothing more from mail related programs.

I am able to send mails to the root user and I can see them in /var/mail with name mail (>/var/mail/mail) with owner and group set to mail and only this user has r/w access I can cat them, naturally).
I want to be able to quickly type >mail
and read them. This is just a control function. I really do not want to create extra users (on soo many containers), maintain their password, change aliases, login and read the mail of root.

After nearly a whole day of searching, I am unable to understand where to read more about it or why this propblem occurs.

This is really very annoying.
Could someone probably explain?

Thanks anyway!

Comment: RTM:  Exim refuses to deliver mail as root.  Mail is delivered as mail or usually to the the user that administers the system via an alias in /etc/aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Make the softlink  `ln -s /var/mail/mail /var/mail/root` and then try to run the `mail` command.